# Why won't my evaporative cooler come on low until it's been set to high?

Tags: evaporative-cooling

Turn the evap knob to "low vent" and nothing. Turn it to "high vent" and it comes on high.  Only then can you successfully turn it back down to low. Exactly the same response happens when using "low cool" and "high cool". This is new. It's always come on for low first; then you could turn it up to high if you choose. What's going on?

Comment: Possibly the motor or starting capacitor is getting weak?

Comment: I agree with Izzy it could be a starting cap issue especially if the motor has separate windings for speed (normal for fans).